# How can I pass a Share intent off to my fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm experimenting with receiving Share intents, but I've come across a situation that I can't wrap my head around. Currently my app shows up as a Share option in other apps, and my Activity receives such these intents just fine. However, I'm having a problem with passing off this intent to a Fragment that I want to handle it. Namely, the Fragment isn't being loaded in time for my Activity to pass it off.

Here's what I have so far in my Activity's `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading new fragment");
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment(), "tag")
                .commit();
    }

    PlaceholderFragment frag = (PlaceholderFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
    Log.i(TAG, "Fragment Exists: " + (frag != null));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null)
    {
        if("text/plain".equals(type))
        {
            //handleIntent(intent); // Doesn't do anything right now
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the log output from when I hit Share in another app and tell it to send the text to my app:

```
I/ActivityStartScreen﹕ Loading new fragment
I/ActivityStartScreen﹕ Fragment Exists: false
I/ActivityStartScreen﹕ Handling Intent
I/PlaceholderFragment﹕ Loading Fragment View
```

As you can see, the Activity wants to hand off the intent before the Fragment is ready, even though I've added a Fragment to the layout before handling the intent. Is part of the problem the fact that the FragmentTransaction needs time to commit? That's the only reason I can imagine the null-check would fail...

What do I do in this situation so that I can pass off the intent to the Fragment once it's ready to go?

Comment: What for? In onActivityCreated of fragment use getActivity().getIntent()

Comment: @Selvin Well shoot, that was simple. For some reason I thought the Activity had to be the one to handle the intent.

Comment: You can also do it inside null check and use set/getArguments of fragment.. I think that null check fail because orientation change